# How to understand 'not as much because... as it is because...'?

Tags: grammar, meaning

From Don Lee Fred Nilsen.(1972). English Adverbials. p.23.

> It should be noted that prepositions are often omitted in standard
> speech and writing as well and also that the reason they are often
> omitted is not **as much** because they are unimportant **as** it is
> because they carry redundant information.

The meaning seems like :

'It should be noted that prepositions are often omitted in standard speech and writing as well and also that the reason they are often omitted is **not** because they are unimportant **but** because they carry redundant information.'

How to understand the usage as much...as in the original sentence?

Comment: **is not as much because of X, as it is because of Y**, means that it is more because of Y than it is because of X.  It would be incorrect to say it means "not because of X".

Comment: @Billy Kerr Are there some articles about this?

Comment: There's a similar expression "not so much something as something" shown here: https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/not-so-much-as - you can use "so" or "as" interchangeably here.

Comment: I would find 'not so much...as' _much_ more idiomatic.

Comment: They are often left our **not primarily for their unimportance but rather they contain redundant information.**

Comment: @Billy Kerr Could it be said 'is not because of X so/as much as it is because of Y'? Like the eample 'I don't feel angry so much as sad.' from [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/not-so-much-as)

Comment: @Mr.Wang Wang Not really.   "Not as/so much X" doesn't mean "not X".

Comment: @Billy Kerr But,how to understand 'I don't feel angry so much as sad.'? It seems to have the same structure as  **'is not because of X so much as it is because of Y'**

Comment: This isn't the same construction as you originally asked about.  There is a different nuance when you say "is not because of X so much as it is because Y".